# PySpark: How to select * from the left table during rdd join

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How to select * in pyspark join

```
impression_rdd.join(
        click_rdd, 
        impression_rdd.session_id == click_rdd.session_id, 
        "left_outer"
    ).select(impression_rdd.*) <------- pseudo code; how do you do this?
```

Basically, the sql equivalent

```
SELECT impression.* FROM impression LEFT JOIN click on (impression.session_id = click.session_id)
```

Comment: Is there an error here, or what are you trying to ask? The RDD API or the SparkSQL API?

Comment: I am trying to ask for the RDD api in python. How do you do .*

Comment: Does this help? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select

Comment: The problem is I don't want `select "*"`. I want select `"impression_rdd.*"`. I only want the `*` to apply to the left table

Comment: Now I understand. Unfortunately, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add alias and a couple of quotes to your pseudocode:

```
(impressions.alias("impressions")
    .join(clicks, ["id"], "left_outer")
    .select("impressions.*"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the RDD API

Answer (score 1):

two other equivalent constructs to [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)'s answer:

```
(impressions.join(clicks, 'session_id', 'left_outer')
    .select(*impressions.columns))
```

and if you only have one column, say 'count', to drop in the right-hand table, this might be more readable.

```
(impressions.join(clicks, 'session_id', 'left_outer')
    .drop('count'))
```